# Autosyncing database for filemaker pro like system

Tags: sql, database, google-apps-script, google-sheets, filemaker

I am working for a Lab. We mainly use google sheets to keep basic data. Whenever a change is made from a computer update is shown on every other computer too. We also use Filemaker Pro on some computers. I want the Structure and form of Filemaker Pro and autosyncing and formulas of googlesheets The one thing i can't seem to figure out on google sheets is how to change a cell's value from another cell. Google App script allows me to do this but i am wondering if there is another way. I am ok with learning another language and platform (SQL) as long as they have what i need. Thank you very much.

Comment: I don’t think it was too broad. It was fairly specific in how to integrate FileMaker with Google Sheets and I provided a solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on FileMaker 16 or later you can use the Google Sheets REST API with the built in JSON functions. You can use older versions if you parse the JSON yourself or use a plugin or custom functions.

You use the Insert from URL script step to perform a GET/PUT request.

Here is the API:
[Google Sheets API v4](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/)